# Multiple line series in wpf application by dvc toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm trying to plot multiple line series by using textbox in wpf application, here is code and output screen shot

Xaml code

```
    <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EECc_Graph"
    xmlns:Compatible="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Compatible;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="EECc_Graph.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="city2">
    <TextBox x:Name="t1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="164,87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="t2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="164,178,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="city" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66"/>
    <Label Content="temperature" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>


    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,311,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Label Content="city2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="t3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="164,234,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="temperature" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="t4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="190,265,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="mchart"  Width="400" Height="250"  Loaded ="McChart_Loaded" Margin="339,107,53,62">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:LineSeries Title=" weather"  IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

            </DVC:LineSeries>

            <DVC:LineSeries Title=" weathers"  IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value"  ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

              </DVC:LineSeries>

        </DVC:Chart.Series>

    </DVC:Chart>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

c# code

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;
  using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
  using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

  namespace EECc_Graph
  {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ChartValues = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ChartValues1 = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       this.mchart.DataContext = ChartValues;
        this.mchart.DataContext = ChartValues1;

        private void McChart_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       string inputX = this.t1.Text.ToString();
        int inputY = Convert.ToInt32(this.t2.Text.ToString());
        ChartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(inputX, inputY));
        string inputX1 = this.t3.Text.ToString();
        int inputY1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.t4.Text.ToString());
        ChartValues1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(inputX1, inputY1));


    }

}
}
```

may i know y im not able to draw multiple line series, collection 2 datacontext is being over written by the collection 1. Is there any mistake in binding....[image]

this is my output screen shot can some one please help

Comment: Where do you link the ChartValues andd ChartValues1 to the xaml

Comment: I'm sorry now i added that to code in mainwindow class @Karthik

Comment: my graph should be as for city 1 there should a line and for city2 there should be a separate line plotted in chart...... cn u please help me @Karthik ... In my application chartvalues 1 is getting overridded with chart values and displaying only city 2 values.....please help me

Comment: okay. Few corrections as the Name="mchart" is parent element and the two lines below the initialize would reset. I could see you are trying to bring line but actually the chart datacontext is set - so it wont work.

Comment: 1) Add Name="line" in the 1st lineseries...2)(line as LineSeries).ItemsSource = ChartValues; in the ctor... 3)Add few more chart values to show up the graph line... - Do the same for 2nd lineseries

Comment: i didnt understand can u please edit in code n send me.....plzzzz @Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in code behind please add these codes:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ChartValues1 = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ();
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ChartValues2 = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ();

    public MainWindow () {
        InitializeComponent ();
        (line1 as LineSeries).ItemsSource = ChartValues1;
        (line2 as LineSeries).ItemsSource = ChartValues2;
    }

    private void Button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //for line1
        string inputX = this.t1.Text.ToString ();
        int inputY = Convert.ToInt32 (this.t2.Text.ToString ());
        ChartValues1.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> (inputX, inputY));
        ChartValues1.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c1 L-1", 22));
        ChartValues1.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c2 L-1", 5));
        ChartValues1.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c3 L-1", 19));

        //for line2
        string inputX1 = this.t3.Text.ToString ();
        int inputY1 = Convert.ToInt32 (this.t2.Text.ToString ());
        ChartValues2.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> (inputX1, inputY1));
        ChartValues2.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c4 L-2", 17));
        ChartValues2.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c5 L-2", 2));
        ChartValues2.Add (new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("c6 L-2", 21));
    }
```

And coming back to xaml, 
please replace your DVC with the below snippet. To notice is that there is a name property added to both lineseries and used in code behind to set the itemsource.

```
<DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10"
               Name="mchart"
               Width="400" Height="250"
               Margin="339,107,53,62">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:LineSeries Title=" weather" Name="line1"
                            IndependentValuePath="Key"
                            DependentValuePath="Value"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            IsSelectionEnabled="True">
            </DVC:LineSeries>
            <DVC:LineSeries Title=" weathers"  Name="line2"
                            IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            IsSelectionEnabled="True">
            </DVC:LineSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

Happy learning!

Comment: thank you ... :) it helped me a lot ... can u please upvote my question @Karthik

Comment: There is a small doubt @Karthik.... how can i get the coordinate points on the lineseries if i place my cursor at any point on the line series